# How can we implement css while creation of PDF using c#

Tags: .net, itext

I am trying to implement media query css while creation of PDF using itextsharp but it can not implement media query using C#

Comment: What exactly have you tried? What exactly did you expect? What exactly happened instead?

Comment: when I create pdf using itextsharp and implement media query for proper formatting of images and fonts , then it is not working

Comment: That isn't any clearer. Nonetheless you mention iTextSharp. Thus, I assume you mean a 5.x version of iText, not yet a 7.x version, and in particular the use of the `XMLWorker` and not the `HtmlConverter`. As far as I remember the iText 5 `XMLWorker` did not support `@media` rules.

Comment: ok, what is there any free DLL to create PDF and which support HTML and CSS

Comment: As hinted above itext 7 offers the `HtmlConverter` in an add-on. And itext 7 is as free as itext 5.